# Android Text Fields default to Chinese

Tags: android

I'm working off of code that isn't originally my own. Right now, I'm having this problem when the user inputs text, it defaults first to the Chinese IME.

I'm sure it's not a java locale setting or anything of the sort. Everything else displays correctly. I'm also not prepopulating the input areas or anything besides having the standard (name) (password) etc.

Thanks.

Comment: @Mudassir What kind of code? There's around 50 source files in my code. I've ben looking through the xml files, but they don't specify language at all. The text input in the java files doesn't specify anything either. They just call for user input. I'm working off of code from another team, so I don't have an easy way to organize things. Right now I'm backtracking through the shared preferences, which I suspect may be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's a general issue for emulators (and probably for some real devices).

For emulator you can run such two commands to remove Pinyin IME (so latin would become default):

```
> adb shell

# mount -rw -o remount /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system

# rm /system/app/PinyinIME.apk
```

the same, but easier to put into Jenkins:

```
> adb shell mount -rw -o remount /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system

> adb shell rm /system/app/PinyinIME.apk
```

You can first check which device is mounted to /system by running

```
# mount
```

in adb shell.

If you need to remove another IME - just change a filename in "rm" command.
Note: this will remove Pinyin IME completely. While you're not completely sure - don't do it on real devices as it would be hard to bring that IME back :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an emulator, I think your keyboard is set to use the chinese keyboard and if you change the keyboard setting your problem should be resolved.

Comment: I have the same problem when testing on an Android phone that definitely does not have the chinese keyboard as default.